# Dagger 2 injection on chained dependencies

Tags: java, android, dagger-2

My apologies for only able to provide the pseudo-code. I am using Dagger 2 in one of my android project and I am having some trouble when there is chained dependencies, for example "A as a B and B has a C" like the following:

```
class A {
  @Inject B b;

  void bootstrap() {
    componentA.inject(this);
  }
}

class B {
  @Inject C c;
}
```

The module and component I have look like the following:

```
moduleA {
  provides B; 
  provides C;
}

componentA {
  void inject(A);
}
```

However, when running the app, C is not injected thus gave me a null pointer exception when referenced.

My question is: **why is C not injected?**

I have tried to have a bootstrap method in B and explicit injecting componentA to B like the following:

```
class B {
   @Inject C c;

   void bootstrap() {
     componentA.inject(this);
   }
}
```

It worked but it doesn't feel right to me as I expected dagger 2 to figure out the dependencies for me rather than passing componentA along the chain. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to pass component A along the chain, you'll have to use constructor parameters instead of @Inject in your provided classes.

```
@Module
public class ModuleA {
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    public A a(B b) {
        return new A(b);
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    public B b(C c) {
        return new B(c);
    } 

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    public C c() {
        return new C();
    } 
}
```